# parser exception in android

Tags: android

I am getting a parser exception. My value is coming from webservice value. I am storing it in a db. That value has single quotes, so I replace them with double quotes. The value gets stored in the db. While retrieving the value and parsing it, I get this error:

Can anybody tell me again how to replace double quotes to single quotes?

```
   03-26 17:11:29.473: WARN/System.err(360): org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 18765: not well-formed (invalid token)
03-26 17:11:29.553: WARN/System.err(360):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:492)
03-26 17:11:29.573: WARN/System.err(360):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:477)
03-26 17:11:29.583: WARN/System.err(360):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:317)
03-26 17:11:29.613: WARN/System.err(360):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:273)
03-26 17:11:29.663: WARN/System.err(360):     at com.inquest.SaxStockDocument.getEventsFromAnXML(SaxStockDocument.java:27)
03-26 17:11:29.673: WARN/System.err(360):     at com.inquest.StockActivity1$StockTask.doInBackground(StockActivity1.java:323)
03-26 17:11:29.693: WARN/System.err(360):     at com.inquest.StockActivity1$StockTask.doInBackground(StockActivity1.java:1)
03-26 17:11:29.773: WARN/System.err(360):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-26 17:11:29.792: WARN/System.err(360):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-26 17:11:29.824: WARN/System.err(360):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-26 17:11:29.863: WARN/System.err(360):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-26 17:11:29.872: WARN/System.err(360):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-26 17:11:29.892: WARN/System.err(360):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-26 17:11:30.053: WARN/InputManagerService(47): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46d459a0
```

Comment: Have you printed out the XML file you are passing to the parse? Looks like your passing it an invalid doc

Comment: From your error it seems value not inserted in DB.. Because No element found in Column 0 error indicates no element in the Column 0..Check that..

Comment: @venkatesh value is storing in db getting value from  but not well formed

Comment: what i don't understand, why do you replace in the server-response single quotes with double?

Comment: And just for better understanding. You get server reponse, replace single quotes with double quotes and store modificated response in db. When you read the reponse from db back you get parser error? is it right?

Comment: @Mur Votema we cannot store single quotes in db so only i changed single quotes to double quotes

Comment: yes you can store anything in the db, you just have to let sqlite escape them for you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I replaced content single quote with two single quote after I parsed value